# Bash make directory based on filename and add .itmsp

Tags: bash, mkdir

I need my script to wrap up files with specific extensions and XML into a directory that is named as per the files. In addition the directory needs to be renamed filename+.itmsp. At the moment the script creates a directory based on the filename but I am not sure how to add the .itmsp to the directory name.

```
#!/bin/bash
path='/Volumes/Drive/TEST'    
cd $path

for FILE in `ls | egrep "xml|mov|mpeg|mpg"`
do
  DIR=`echo $FILE | cut -d '.' -f 1`
  mkdir -p $DIR
  mv $FILE $DIR
done
```

Comment: To clarify, if you have a file named `foo.mov` you want to create a directory named `foo.itmsp`?  Do you want to move `foo.mov` into `foo.itmsp/` afterwards?

Comment: I have two files 1 called foo.xml and 1 called foo.mov/mpg/mpeg depending on the video file. and I want to move these two files into a directory called foo.itmsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is bash:

```
cd /Volumes/Drive/TEST
for FILE in *.{xml,mov,mpeg,mpg}
do
  # remove the last dot and subsequent chars, then add new ext
  DIR="${FILE%.*}.itmsp"
  mkdir -p "$DIR"
  mv "$FILE" "$DIR"
done
```

Comment: That works and is much nicer than the cut option - thank you. Only little thingh is that it creates an additional directory called *.itmsp that is empty - but it can be removed

Comment: the only way I can think that would happen is if the pattern `*.{xml,mov,mpeg,mpg}` matched no files, and you have the shell option `nullglob` turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Just append .itmsp to $DIR like "$DIR.itmsp".

Comment: The directory does have .itmsp added. But with no files in it and it cuts the extension of the files outside of the directory